# How do I snap my driver's keyframe to the reference point in the driver's graph editor?

Tags: rigging, drivers

I am just working on some corrective shape keys for my character. These shape keys will be triggered by drivers. E.g. when my shin rotates I want the corrective shape key for my knee to be triggered.

When referencing my shin bone's local x rotation in the drivers panel a little reference point appears in the graph editor. That point indicates the current rotation of my shin. Now I want my keyframe with the value of 1 to be at the exact same position as the reference point. Is there a fast way on how to snap my keyframe's position to the position of the reference point?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In drivers editor window you can manually set the values of the curve control points, assuming that X is named (uncorrectly) "Key Frame" and represents the value of the expression, while Y (named Value) represents the output.

Dotted lines indicate the actual values of input and output of the curve.

In my example when the driver expression is 0.0 output is 0.0, expr 2.0 output 3.0, expr 4.0 output 0.0.

Snapping is on about X values ("Nearest Frame"), but it can be switched off with the drop down menu.

Shift right click lets you place the 2D cursor, its values can be edited in the "View" tab, then you can use Shift S > "Selection to cursor", to snap there the control point.

[image]